# Installing esx 3.5 on hpblade 460c G7

Tags: vmware-esx, blade-server

I was trying to install ESX 3.5 on hp blade 460c but it fails with error no 'network adapter is detected'. Anybody has work around for this.

I also tried to install ESX 4.1, it also had the same problem but in case of 4.1 there is support to add your custom driver while installing. So I added NIC drivers and installation completed successfully. ESX 3.5 installtion does not support adding custom drivers while installing.

I can't use ESX 4.1 because it does not support 'license server' configuration and only asks for license file(key). I do not have license keys, I only have vmware license server. That is the reason I have to be with ESX 3.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The G7 version of the BL460c doesn't support 3.5 and actually only supports 4.x with their own drivers/version from hp.com. Next time read their quickspecs.

Comment: I read that but I was actually trying to find if there is any tweak available to proceed with installation. Anyways thanks for your help.

Comment: Nope the only drivers for that NIC/CNA is a 64-bit one for 4.x only.